# Unexpected working of SUID

Tags: linux, permissions

I am on Linux Mint.

I have added the SUID bit to a script using the following command:

```
chmod u+s script.sh
```

as confirmed by `ll` (`ls -laF`):

[image: ll (ls -laF) output]

Now, if I login using another user, I can't execute the `script.sh` file;
I get a "Permission denied" error:

[image: screenshot: execution of ./script.sh gets "Permission denied"]

What am I doing wrong?

ASAIK, SUID allows anybody to execute the program as the owner.

Comment: Related: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364/108618).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you haven’t given execute permission
to anybody but the file’s owner. 
The mode is currently 4764. 
The last two digits have to be 5 or 7 for it to be executable by others.

  Use 4755. 
  It’s rare that you want a file to be writable by people other than the owner. 
  There are cases where you want this,
  but the default should be
  *NN*
  44,
  *NN*
  55 or
  *NN*
  11 (or less)
  unless you can justify making the file writable.

Setuid files should ***never** never **ever***
be writable by anybody other than the file’s owner.
The rest of the answer: setuid (usually) doesn’t work on scripts,
so, even if you chmod the script to 4755
and give the other user execute permission,
it will run as the user that invoked it, not as the owner of the file.

Comment: So, if it were any kind of executable like compiled C file, then it would SUID bit allows other users to execute the file as the file owner. Correct?

Comment: Right.  Provided the low-order bits of the mode ***allow*** the other user to execute the file in the first place.

Comment: That I didn't understand. If lower bits need to allow other users to execute the first, then what's the need of SUID ?